# Apple Watch - How to draw Map directions

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, directions

I have seen Apple Watch videos where it shows directions. I also tried to show directions on a map in the Apple Watch. I have been trying hard but I could not find the any solution as there are limited methods in `WKInterfaceMap`.

Is there any solution please help me out with some links or some docs which are available publicly.

I will try to make it possible at my end as it is available on video.

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] to improve your post.

Comment: @Om, Please check below link if this can help you out. [HANDS-ON WITH THE WATCHKIT SDK – CREATING A NAVIGATION APP](http://sdkblog.skobbler.com/hands-on-with-the-watchkit-sdk-creating-a-navigation-app/#.VTj3QCGqqkp)